# Variable equals another variable and then equals another variable

Tags: javascript, code

I have been trying to get a grasp of WordPress Theme Development. I have some understanding of JavaScript and PHP.  When I was trying to figure out how to use the media uploader and I found several articles using lines of code like below:

```
mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose a Profile Picture',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Picture'
        },
        multiple: false
    });
```

It does not make sense to me to use `"mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({});"`. Why not just use `mediaUploader = wp.media({})`? I appreciate any help I can get on this because I really want to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript (and PHP, too), you can save a few lines of code by assigning multiple variables at once. In this example, the function `wp.media()` is called and immediately assigned to `wp.media.frames.file_frame`. The author wanted to use the same value for `mediaUploader` so they added it in the same assignment statement.

Another way to look at it is

```js
// Option 1: single function call, multiple assignments    
wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({...});
mediaUploader              = wp.media.frames.file_frame;

// Option 2: multiple function calls, multiple assignments
wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({...});
mediaUploader              = wp.media({...});
```

This can be useful if you're assigning a value to a global object but want to manipulate the value locally without affecting the global. In this case, the author can assign the value to `wp.media.frames.file_frame` so it's available there, and use `mediaUploader` locally inside a function without affecting the value of the other scoped variable.